# Microsoft Chatbot Framework Chat not initiating properly

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot

[View the video which is not working](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1phUs3e_wjGOifLhqKA5PB-zDvMfDypuo/view)

I have created the MS bot in nodejs with dialog flow

Here's the sample [Multi-turn Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt) bot which I altered for creating my bot.

**Problem Statement:** While starting the conversation it's not initiating properly. It's slow to respond or not starting conversation which it should because I have added `onMembersAdded` to send activity to respond once the page is loaded.

It's working in emulator but not working in the directline.

```
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
        console.log('Running dialog with Message Activity.');

        // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
        await this.dialog.run(context, this.dialogState);

        // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
        await next();
    });

this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
        const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
        for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
            if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                await context.sendActivity('Hi! This is SOLIZE assistant bot. We assist you in fast staffing placements.');
                await dialog.run(context, conversationState.createProperty('DialogState'));
            }
        }

        // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
        await next();
    });
```

Comment: Can you verify that the bot is still responding slow at conversation start? I was also experiencing slowness these last couple of weeks, but it cleared up today on its own.